# How to turn age in years into months?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am using postgreSQL - pgAdmin. 
I need to add to the table session_users a feature that calculates the user seniority in **months**.

My code is:

```
ALTER TABLE session_users ADD signup_seniority_attribute interval;      
update session_users su set signup_seniority_attribute=
(select age(signup_date) from session_users su1 where su1.user_id=su.user_id 
and is_the_account_master= 'N' group by su1.signup_date, su.signup_date);
```

[the input for example is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29Ev9.png)

i need to turn to months: for example  3 years 4 months = 40 months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rest of you query is correct, you should be able to SELECT a date in months using the date_part function and a bit of maths. So something like...

```
ALTER TABLE session_users ADD signup_seniority_attribute interval;      
UPDATE session_users su 
SET signup_seniority_attribute=
(SELECT(date_part('YEAR', age(su1.signup_date)) * 12) + date_part('MONTH', age(dob)) 
 AS Age_in_months 
 FROM session_users su1 
 WHERE su1.user_id=su.user_id 
 AND is_the_account_master= 'N');
```

Note I've only altered the subquery at the end, I haven't tested the rest of your query.

Here is an example of the date_part and maths on their own: [Let's buy some apples!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/04920/2)

Answer (score 0):

If i am geting your question right you should look into [DATEDIFF](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff) function.

Answer (score 0):

```
EXTRACT(year FROM age(now(),su.signup_date))*12 + EXTRACT(month FROM age(now(),su.signup_date))
```

More explanations here - http://www.lexykassan.com/coding-conundrums/calculating-months-between-dates-in-postgresql/